# What does is not None stands for in django/python?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to display a not valid message when my html form field is empty. But the code below triggers the "if block" when the field is empty and the "else block" when the field is not empty.

I wrote it this way because this seems to do the job. But I'm confused. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

```
if(request.POST['amount'] is not None):

   os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,str(uploaded_file.name) ))
            messages.success(request,('Invalid Field....'))
            return redirect('assignFine')
else:
   form = Fine(amount=request.POST['amount'],numberPlate=num,policeUsername=request.user)
            form.save()
```

Comment: Did you test if it goes to the `else` block if the input is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the phrase below to check if `amount` parameter exists in `request.POST`:

```py
if 'amount' in request.POST:
    # Your code
else:
    # Else case
```

You can use `not in` operator to have negative if/else phrase:

```py
if 'amount' not in request.POST:
    # No 'amount' available
else:
    # There is 'amount' parameter
```

**[Edit]**

And to check if the value is not `empty`, `False`, or `None`  you can check it in this way:

```py
if 'amount' in request.POST and request.POST['amount']:
    # 'amount' exists, and is not 'empty', 'False', or 'None'
```

Comment: And what if `amount` is in the dictionary, but with a `None` value?

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
if request.POST['amount'] is not None:
```

Means: if the parameter *exists* (is *not* `None`), do the block below, otherwise do the `else` part. For this to make sense, if the `amount` exists we should create a `Fine`, otherwise we signal an error. Your conditions appear to be switched!

Depending on the expected values of the `amount` parameter, I'd also consider using this version:

```
if request.POST['amount']:
  # create fine
else:
  # signal an error
```

It's shorter, and means: if the `amount` is *not* `None`, or `''`, or `False`, or `0` or any other falsey values in Python, do the block below, otherwise do the `else` part.

Comment: more verbose, but also more precise for many uses where falsy values may be valid

Comment: But if it is as you say. Then shouldn't the if request.POST['amount']  is not none: block be executed when the amount exist?

Comment: @sayeedk06 oh! I see your point now. I believe your conditions are switched! Also check what value is arriving in the parameter, maybe is not `None`, but it's an empty string. That's why I prefer the second version in my answer.